# Alter a part of an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array,

```
Array
        (
            [0]Array
                (
                    [ftid] 2
                    [fname] Ho Type
                    [flabelid] Array
                        (
                            [0] 1000
                            [1] 1001
                            [2] 1002
                            [3] 1003
                            [4] 1004
                        )

                    [flabels] Array
                        (
                            [0] All
                            [1] Si Fam
                            [2] Toho
                            [3] Con Co
                            [4] Mob Ho
                        )

                )

            [1] Array
                (
                    [ftid] 3
                    [fname] Li Pri
                    [flabelid] Array
                        (
                            [0] 1000
                            [1] 1007
                            [2] 1008
                        )

                    [flabels] Array
                        (
                            [0] All
                            [1] 50M
                            [2] 50K

                        )

                )
        )
```

how would I change `Ho Type` which is the `fname` without destroying the array. What I mean is only change that specific part? Please help. Cheers!

Comment: `$Array[0]['fname'] = 'something';` consider looking at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Should your question pertain to finding that `fname` in your array list, then you're probably looking for a `foreach` and `if` construct prior assigning a new text string. Or did you try something else?

Comment: no wonder why this question got many downvotes, 'twas my fault really, I never really thought of this. FFFF! I should close this one. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array[0]['fname'] = $new_value;
```

considering `$array` is the name of your array & `$new_value` as new value